# how do i create a scatter plot with 2 1-D arrays?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, charts, mschart, scatter-plot

my only objective is to create a scatter plot with only x and y axes. the data source should be from a 1 dimensional array.

say i have these arrays:

- x() as Object ' for x axis values
- y() as Object ' for y axis values

and i have this chart:

chart1

the arrays are already filled with data. my question is: how do i enter the array data on chart1 such that x() values will be the x-axis values for chart 1 and y() will be the y-axis values for chart 1. what code should i use to make the chart show a scatter plot using the data from the arrays?

your reply will be very much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at chart properties under Chart>Series and change Series1 ChartType to Point.

```
    Dim x() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    Dim y() As Integer = {2, 1, 7, 3, 3}

    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
```

Comment: this has answered my question. I will stick with the Chart control for now and will learn to use it before trying the zedgraph. again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Zedgraph. It's a free graphing library that works great. There are lots of code samples on their website that allow you to do what you're asking. [Zedgraph Downloads](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/) Their website seems to be having issues right now, but the download session works and contains all of their sample files.